# Несколько вопросов относительно С++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.
Хотел бы задать несколько вопросов по С++, не по самому синтаксису, а скорее по его применению, использованию.
Просто несколько немного общих таких вопросов, в которых я чуть сомневаюсь и не до конца понимаю их.

Мне вот интересно... Чем занимаются С++ разработчики? Что они пишут и с помощью чего?
Как-то слышал, что на С++ обычно пишут ядро программы, а как они это делают, создают в Visual Studio empty project и начинают как-то там его писать?
А если нужен, к примеру, графический интерфейс, то они используют MFC? Т.е. большинство приложений, которые мы видим пишутся при помощи MFC?
Ну просто можно писать на С++ WinAPI проекты, но там попросту долго писать интерфейс будет, т.е. в таком случае MFC - это практически то же, что и на WinAPI писать, просто мы работаем "более крупными штрихами", ведь немало классов MFC и т.п. это просто что-то вроде обёртки для API-функций, верно?
Ещё вроде бы можно использовать технологию WinForms, но это скорее уже ближе к .NET как мне кажется, чем к самому С++, да и с WinForms вроде как удобнее работать, используя C# (мне так кажется).

А если нужно писать под Linux, OS X? Что используют тогда?
Ну под Linux, собственно как и под Windows я знаю, что есть библиотеки, инструментарии разработки, типа Qt, GTK+; 
Т.е. обычно пишут на С++ на них, или нет?

А вот взять к примеру разработчиков компьютерных игр.. Они ведь вроде тоже на С++ пишутся большинство. Как им и с чем приходится работать?

Также было бы интересно послушать мнения людей, которые специализируются в области С++, senior programmer в этой области..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Чем занимаются С++ разработчики?

Пишут программы! А еще борются с ограничениями языка :-)

> Что они пишут и с помощью чего?

Средства разработки - это отдельный вопрос. Самые известные - среды MS Visual Studio (С++ входит в нее), Embarcadero (бывший Borland) RAD Studio (C++ Builder). Из отдельных компиляторов - gcc, Intel C++ Compiler (интегрируется с MSVS)

Что пишут? Разные вещи. Начиная от приложений типа калькуляторов, заканчивая играми, операционными системами и тяжелыми программами, работающими с БД

> а как они это делают, создают в Visual Studio empty project и начинают как-то там его писать?

Сначала нужно спроектировать, а затем уже писать.

Ну, например, можно и так. А можно начать не с empty project, а модифицировать уже существующее.

> А если нужен, к примеру, графический интерфейс, то они используют MFC?

Не обязательно. Можно использовать напрямую вызовы Win32API, но это не очень удобно. А можно использовать кроссплатформенные библиотеки вроде Qt, GTK+, wxWidgets и пр. А еще если нужен графический интерфейс игры, то можно взять или существующий движок (например, Auran Jet), или написать его самому.

> Т.е. большинство приложений, которые мы видим пишутся при помощи MFC?

!?!?!?!? Вывод весьма странный.

> ведь немало классов MFC и т.п. это просто что-то вроде обёртки для API-функций, верно?

Да, верно. MFC - по сути удобная оболочка для Win32API + куча полезных бонусов. Например, весьма удобен класс CString.

> Что используют тогда?

gcc :-)

> Т.е. обычно пишут на С++ на них, или нет?

И на C++ пишут тоже. Другой вопрос, что С++ иногда бывает избыточен. Маленькую простую программу возможно написать и на Си. И она будет существенно проще. А еще есть куча других языков. Обработку файлов мне удобнее делать с помощью shell-скриптов. Обрабатывать файлы со строковыми данными - с помощью perl. В Си/C++, увы, работа со строками реализована не очень удобно. Но это не означает, что С/C++ для этого непригодны.

Answer (score 2):

> А вот взять к примеру разработчиков
> компьютерных игр.. Они ведь вроде тоже
> на С++ пишутся большинство. Как им и с
> чем приходится работать?

Игры традиционно(отчасти - из-за огромного количества примеров и других исходников) пишут на C++, но вообще это можно делать на чем угодно.
Создание игр - это вообще одна из самых сложных областей программирования(тем не менее, это не значит, что небольшие проекты не под силу новичку), она, как правило, включает в себя различные базовые алгоритмы(вроде бинарного поиска, графов, работы со строками...), работу со звуком(библиотеки DirectSound/OpenAL/Bass и т.п.), с графикой(библиотеки OpenGL/DirectX/своя софтверная реализация), работу с файловой системой и кучу других задач. 

Поскольку каждая из вышеописанных областей весьма немаленькая, зачастую отдельными частями игры(графикой, физическим движком, игровой логикой, звуком и т.п.) занимаются отдельные люди, специализирующиеся на этом.

C++ - очень мощный язык. Иногда программы на нем существенно длиннее программ, написанных на более высокоуровневых языках. Но, как правило, причина только в недостаточном количестве стандартных функций, и при использовании мощных библиотек вроде STL/Boost/Loki и т.п. код может стать очень красивым,лаконичным и понятным.